# CASE SQL statement oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, case, between

my requirement is if first condition is null then check for the second condition if second condition is null as well then third condition in oracle database, so I am trying to achieve this by case statement as shown below but getting an error as missing expression/missing keyword.

```
CASE
     WHEN (TRUNC( OTA_EVENTS.COURSE_START_DATE) BETWEEN PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_F.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_F.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE ) IS NULL  
     then  (TRUNC(OTA_DELEGATE_BOOKINGS.Date_Booking_Placed) BETWEEN PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_F.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_F.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE) 
     ELSE (TRUNC(OTA_DELEGATE_BOOKINGS.DATE_STATUS_CHANGED) BETWEEN PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_F.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_F.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE) 
END
```

Please help if there is any other way to achieve this

Comment: Sample data and desired results would certainly help.  The question is pretty clear.  The code sample seems to have nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 1):

> my requirement is if first condition is null then check for the second condition if second condition is null as well then third condition in oracle database

I don't see what your code has to do with this question (it is using `between` rather than `NULL` comparison.  ABut what you are describing is `COALESCE()`:

```
select coalesce(a, b, c)
```

This can take as many arguments as you need.  It returns the first non-`NULL` value.

Answer (score 0):

It means you need `OR` between your conditions:

```
(TRUNC(OTA_EVENTS.COURSE_START_DATE) 
            BETWEEN PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_F.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE 
                AND PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_F.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
OR ( TRUNC(OTA_DELEGATE_BOOKINGS.DATE_BOOKING_PLACED) 
            BETWEEN PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_F.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE 
                AND PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_F.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE )
OR ( TRUNC(OTA_DELEGATE_BOOKINGS.DATE_STATUS_CHANGED) 
            BETWEEN PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_F.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE 
                AND PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_F.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE ))
```